# gcloud crashed (NotADirectoryError): (Errno 20) Not a directory: 'xdg-settings' appeared after type: gcloud init

Tags: macos, installation, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, init

I got problem with command line: "gcloud init" after installed successfully the google cloud SDK in local machine. The error appeared as below:

> cloud init
>
> Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.
>
> Your current configuration has been set to: [default]
>
> You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
> gcloud init --skip-diagnostics
>
> Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
> Checking network connection...done.
>
> Reachability Check passed.
>
> Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).
>
> You must log in to continue. Would you like to log in (Y/n)?  Y
>
> ERROR: gcloud crashed (NotADirectoryError): [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'xdg-settings'
>
> If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
>
> gcloud feedback
>
> To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
>
> gcloud info --run-diagnostics "

I tried to fix by using [this link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/troubleshooting/#permissionerror-on-macos-catalina)  but it did not work in my environment. Please let me know if you have any idea and want me to provide anything, feel free to ask me.

Best Regards,
PNV

Comment: What version of Cloud SDK are you using? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/version. There are updates that fix bugs in general.

Comment: gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 301.0.0
bq 2.0.58
core 2020.07.10
gsutil 4.51

Comment: I know this may cause you some work but to report an issue with Google Cloud SDK is to use Google Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0  I hope this is not inconvenient to you.

Comment: But before then, you may try to update your Cloud SDK https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by doing the steps [here:](https://superuser.com/questions/911735/how-do-i-use-xdg-open-from-xdg-utils-on-mac-osx)

```sh
brew install libxslt xmlto
export XML_CATALOG_FILES="/usr/local/etc/xml/catalog"
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils
cd xdg-utils
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Note that I also had to install lynx using `brew install lynx` cause I was getting this issue:

```sh
Note: Writing xdg-settings.1
/usr/local/bin/xmlto txt desc/xdg-desktop-menu.xml
No way to convert HTML to text found.
Try either installing text web browser(lynx/w3m/links) or use option --with-fop
make[1]: *** [xdg-desktop-menu.txt] Error 1
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```